# Laravel Excel saber como insertar una fila al cumplir una condición

Tags: laravel, excel

Hola buenos días tengo un problema quiero en un Excel echo con laravel excel insertar una fila con valores fijos cuando el valor de pedido no se igual al anterior
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que uso para exportar el archivo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.